# Join two string sequences in xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath

How can I create the union of two string sequences in xpath 2.0?

Having those two functions...

```
<xsl:function name="my:foo" as="xs:string*">
    ....
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="my:bar" as="xs:string*">
    ....
</xsl:function>
```

I want to iterate over both resulting string sequences like:

```
<xsl:variable name="myResult" select="for $s in my:foo() ??union?? my:bar() return my:doSomethingWith($s)" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Just found the answer in the book "XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 4th Edition", chapter 10 "The Comma Operator":

> The operands of the «,» operator can be any two sequences. Of course, a single item is itself a sequence,
>   so the operands can also be single items. Either of the sequences can be empty, in which case the result
>   of the expression is the value of the other operand.

So it would look like:

```
<xsl:variable name="myResult" select="for $s in (my:foo(), my:bar()) return my:doSomethingWith($s)" />
```